# how to get total cost of keyword in adwords api

Tags: java, api, google-ads-api

using Adwords API:
1.Used criterion

```
{
selectorBuilder builder = new SelectorBuilder();
    Selector selector = builder
        .fields(
            AdGroupCriterionField.Id,
            AdGroupCriterionField.CriteriaType,
            AdGroupCriterionField.KeywordMatchType,
            AdGroupCriterionField.KeywordText,
            AdGroupCriterionField.CpcBid)
        .orderAscBy(AdGroupCriterionField.KeywordText)
        .offset(offset)
        .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
        .in(AdGroupCriterionField.AdGroupId, adGroupId.toString())
        .in(AdGroupCriterionField.CriteriaType, "KEYWORD")
        .build();

    while (morePages) {
      // Get all ad group criteria.
      AdGroupCriterionPage page = adGroupCriterionService.get(selector);
      AdGroupCriterion[] af=page.getEntries();
      BiddableAdGroupCriterion biddableAdGroupCriterion = new BiddableAdGroupCriterion();
      biddableAdGroupCriterion = (BiddableAdGroupCriterion)af[0];
      for (Bids bids : biddableAdGroupCriterion.getBiddingStrategyConfiguration().getBids()) {}
    }           
}
```

> Used:EstimateKeyword it return The Error No_AdGroup_ForKeyword Error.
>
> Used:reports but reports are returning nothing even though i am getting campaign and adds in test account via api

Any suggestion (Using eclipse and JAVA 8)

Comment: I'm also interested in this. Can you share how do you solve the problem?